# Extjs Set fieldLabel dynamically fires only once

Tags: extjs

I've tried this:

```
Ext.override(Ext.form.Field, {
setFieldLabel: function(text) {         
    if (this.rendered) {             
        var labelSeparator = this.labelSeparator;               
        if (typeof labelSeparator == 'undefined') {                 
             if (this.ownerCt && this.ownerCt.layout && typeof
             this.ownerCt.layout.labelSeparator != 'undefined')                     
                   labelSeparator = this.ownerCt.layout.labelSeparator;                 
             else                    
                  labelSeparator = '';            
        }               
        var formItem = this.el.up('.x-form-item', 10); 
        if (formItem) {
             var label = formItem.child('.x-form-item-label'); 
             if (label)                     
                  label.update(text + labelSeparator);             
        }         
} else            
       this.fieldLabel = text;     
} 
})
```

but it only fires once.
I have a formpanel (form a) that lets you edit a set of data, and that set of data will be the fieldLabel of another form (form b). At start, when I "edit" the fieldLabel from form a, it works, (form b's fieldLabel is changed), but after opening form b from a button (e.i. Create button), and editting the fieldLabel (inputtin in a textfield) from form a again, the fieldLabel in form b is not changed.

formItem = this.el.up('.x-form-item', 10); becomes null.
how to resolve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solve:

```
Ext.override(Ext.form.Field, {
    setFieldLabel: function(text) {
        if (this.rendered) {
            var labelSeparator = this.labelSeparator;
            if (typeof labelSeparator == 'undefined') {
                if (this.ownerCt && this.ownerCt.layout && typeof this.ownerCt.layout.labelSeparator != 'undefined')
                    labelSeparator = this.ownerCt.layout.labelSeparator;
                else
                    labelSeparator = '';
            }
            var formItem = this.el.up('.x-form-item', 10);
            if (formItem) {
                var label = formItem.child('.x-form-item-label');
                if (label)
                    label.update(text + labelSeparator);
            } else {
                this.labelEl.update(text);
            }
        } else {
            this.fieldLabel = text;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call setText() method. More simple.